# Meaning of "for good or ill"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw a scene in *Downton Abbey* in which one character said,

> Here we are, ma'am, Crawley House. For good or ill.

What does "for good or ill" mean here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase *for good or ill* is a slightly antiquated way of saying ["for better or worse"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/what-is-for-the-better-or-worse).

Answer (score 2):

I believe it to be equivalent to *for better or worse* or the recently over-wrung *it is what it is*.

Comment: i totally makes sense, thank you. although sorry because my reputation is not high enough to vote for you.

Comment: You are welcome.  Feel free to click the check mark to accept whichever answer you accept as the correct one.